# How to validate multidimensional array with with jquery validate

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array, jquery-validate

I follow some tutorial for validate input array,

```
name="surname[]"
```

This work perfectly, but if I have a input like this (with php variables)

```
name="surname[<?=id?>][<?=number?>][]"
```

It don't work.

Comment: I've formatted your question to use proper code blocks; However, you still need to explain exactly *how* you're trying to validate the input. As it stands, the question is extremely unclear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this --

```
<select multiple required class="form-control" name="martial_arts[]">

  OR

  <input type="text" name="surname[]" />
```

in  validate method use this --

```
rules: {
         'martial_arts[]': {
                        required: true,
                    }
       }

  OR

    rules: {
         'surname[]': {
                        required: true,
                    }
       }
```

Comment: I just do this, but if array is multidimensional
<input type="text" name="surname[][][]" />
don't work

Comment: so you have to try this --   rules: {
         'surname[][][]': {
                        required: true,
                    }
       }

Comment: Filippo i have checked this it`s working perfectly...now u can use this... rules: { 'surname[][][]': { required: true, } }

Comment: my array is:

<input type="text" name="surname[id][number][]" />
id and number pass with php, then i have two input for example with different variables (id and number). I have just try rules:{'surname[][][]'... but don't work

Comment: This work well, but if i have more input with array? http://jsfiddle.net/Gy24q/328/

Comment: use like that you have to make it dynamic -- http://jsfiddle.net/soravgarg/Gy24q/337/

Comment: How i make it dynamic? the numbers you see ([1][22][] and [2][25][] are insert with a php foreach, Then how can i do with jquery?